# Mocking an injected field in unit tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a `Presenter` class which uses a field injected through Dagger, it looks something like this:

```
public class RssListPresenter {

    @Inject
    RssService rssService; // <-- injected field

    public RssListPresenter() {
        setupDI();
    }

    private void setupDI() {
        DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
                .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    }

    public void loadItems() {
        Rss rss = rssService.getRssFeed()
        // ....
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. Now, I would like to unit test the `RssListPresenter` class. The question is how do I provide a mock `RssService` to the presenter?

Ofcourse I can add a new method `setRssService(RssService rssService)` to the presenter and use it to provide the mock from unit tests, but adding this method just for unit tests does not feel right. What would be the correct way to handle this?

For completeness here are the module and component declarations:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = NetworkModule.class)
public interface NetworkComponent {
    void inject(RssListPresenter presenter);
}

@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
        // ... 
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RssService providePcWorldRssService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(RssService.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: for once: when you don't have unit test yet how do you know it works fine? and second: the field is neither `private` nor `final`, so you can simply set it from your TestClass (if it is in the same package).

Comment: 1 - you run the app, and when the field is not injected you see the results instantly :), 2 - I think I will go with construction injection as suggested below, but thanks for your suggestions too.

Comment: *"and when the field is not injected you see the results instantly :)"* OK, but that is "the DI framwork works" and this is not my understanding of "Everything works fine" which includes the actual behavior of *my* code, not the code of any framework. That's why I asked... ;o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Property injection is like that is not so easy to test. In this case, Constructor injection is much better. Refactor your constructor to look like this:

```
private final RssService rssService;

@Inject
public RssListPresenter(RssService rssService) {
        this.rssService = rssService;
}
```

Now you can test it easily:

```
//mocks
RssService mockRssService;

//system under test
RssListPresenter rssListPresenter;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockRssService = Mockito.mock(RssService.class);
    rssListPresenter = new RssListPresenter(mockRssService);
}
```

You probably shouldn't be using `DaggerNetworkComponent.inject(this)` inside `RssListPresenter`. Instead you should be configuring dagger so that when it injects members into your top-level classes (`Activity`, `Fragment`, `Service`) it can access the object graph and create an instance of your `RssPresenter`.

Why only put injectors in `Activity` and `Service` and not in something like `RssListPresenter`? These are classes that are instantiated by the Android system and so you have no choice but to use injectors.

To clarify, `Activity`, `Fragment` etc. are ideal **injection targets**. `RssListPresenter` etc. are **injected dependencies**. You need to configure the dependency **injection framework**, dagger,  so that it can provide the correct dependencies to inject into the injection targets.

So you will also need to write a `@Provides` method for `RssListPresenter`

```
@Provides provideRssListPresenter(RssService rssService) {
    return new RssListPresenteR(rssService);
}
```

Comment: What would happen if he adds another constructor that takes `RssService` parameter only for the testing purposes?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Not sure why would you want to do that. You want to design your classes so that they are clean and do not have to change them just for testing, right?

Comment: @DavidRawson Absolutely, just asked if the OP is in position at this point, where he cannot afford refactoring his only constructor.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the fundamental reason `Activity`, `Fragment`, etc. are injection targets is because they're instantiated by the Android framework and require a no-arg constructor.

Comment: You just made me realize how stupid I am ! I wasted 2.5 hours struggling to inject property which was done in split second after reading your answer. You are a lifesaver man. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: the question is how to mock an injected field. not how to avoid it so you can easily mock. there are situations that you can not use constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your class violates some of the `S.O.L.I.D` principles, and this makes it very difficult to unit test it. Your class for sure violats the SRP(Single Responsability Principle) as it has **more than one** reason to change. There is also a possible Dependency Inversion violation.

I advice to rethink the model of the classes, so that each of them performs a specific function, and has one reason to change.